# which type of attribute of the subclass can not be inherited?

Tags: java

```
class Test4{
    int a=2;
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Test4 test4=new Test4();
    Test4 test5=new Test5();
    System.out.println("test4_a="+test4.a);
    System.out.println("test5_a="+test5.a);
    System.out.println(test4.a==test5.a);
    }
}
class Test5 extends Test4{
    float a=2.0f;
}
```

The two attributes'types are not the same.Why "test4.a==test5.a" is still true?
Please expain the attributes of the subclass in detail.Thanks!

Comment: because `2.0` and `2` are the same number, the `==` operator compares the value of its two operands.

Comment: one is int,another is float.How can they be the same number?

Comment: `float` and `int` are their types, not their values. Two variables only have to have the same value to satisfy `==`.

Comment: So if I offer you $2k or $2.0k, you would say those are two different offers?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I *think* is confusing you. See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a = 5;
    double b = 5.0;
    short c = 5;
    
    System.out.println(a == b);
    System.out.println(b == c);
    
    int[] x = {1,2,3};
    int[] y = {1,2,3};
    
    System.out.println(x == y);
    
}
```

The results of this are

> true
>
> true
>
> false

Why? *Base types*, also known as [primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), are compared by value. As I said above, the offer of $2k and $2.0k are the same offer. They represent the same value.

But objects, such as an arrays, should be compared by their equals() method. Using the default equals operator `==` just compares memory locations. So two separate arrays, both with equal objects but different objects in memory, are not judged equal.  On the other hand, if I had said

```
int[] y = x;
```

Then `x == y` would be true, because they would be pointing to the same object in memory.

Note: I realize arrays may not have been the best example, as comparing arrays should be done with the static `Arrays.equals(int[], int[])` method for a true deep search. `x.equals(y)` would still be false, but `Arrays.equals(x,y)` would give you true

Comment: Oh,thanks a lot.It's my fault.I mislead you another question.Now I change my code in Test5.I change "float a=2.0f;" into "String a="abc".Why  "test4.a==test5.a" is still true?   What i want to kwnow is the attributes between subclass and superclass.

Comment: I didn't read the question as carefully as I should. Read @Flavio 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The trick of this exercise is that `test5` is declared as a `Test4` type, although instantiated as a `Test5`.
When you access `test5.a`, you are actually taking the value of `Test4.a`. There is no float to integer comparison. You can easily check this by defining the float to be equal to `5.0f`: the comparison will be `true` anyway, because you are comparing a variable with itself.

This is called [hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154348/java-field-hiding), by the way. It's very confusing, you should know it exists only in order to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you!I have seen the page of "hiding".It helps me a lot.Maybe i can say in this way.If the superclass has attributes,like the a of "int a=2;",the superclass have hided the "a" in subclass,no matter which type of "a" is in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

test5 is an instance of Test5 (it really is, even though it was declarated as Test4), which has *a* float member variable, hiding the superclass' *a* int member variable.

test4 is an instance of Test4 and therefore has an int member variable.
test4.a == test5.a, because their values are the same.